# How do i delete a select item from javascript once a user clicks on one of the select items

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete a specific option in javascript when the user clicks on the option so that the user does no click on a duplicate option. I used this code to append to the website.

```
    var countries = ['Ghana', 'USA', 'London']
    var html = ""
    for (let index = 0; index < countries.length; index++) {
      const element = countries[index];
      html+="<option value='"+element+"'>"+element+"</option>"
    }

    $('#from').html(html)
  }
```

Comment: I think disabling instead of deleting the option is better experience. BTW, what you can do: add a event listener to the parent of the options and when any of the option is selected disable/delete that particular option element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change code as per this, adding select in html var and class name so that you can bind click event to it to fulfill the need.

```
var countries = ['Ghana', 'USA', 'London']
var html = "<select class='myselect'>"
for (let index = 0; index < countries.length; index++) {
  const element = countries[index];
  html+="<option value='"+element+"'>"+element+"</option>"
}
html+="</select>"
$('#from').html(html)

//click event for selected option
$(".myselect option").click(function(){

$(".myselect option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").remove()
    
})
```